# how to remove duplicate data set labels in chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have the following bar chart that I loop through an array to add in new datasets as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.Chart.length; i++) {
            barChartData.datasets.push({
                label: this.Chart[i].name,
                backgroundColor: this.chart[i].color
                data: [{
                    x: //set details
                    y: //set details
                }],
            });
        }

        this.data = {
            labels: moment.months(),
            datasets: barChartData.datasets


        };

        this.config = {
            type: 'bar',
            data: this.data,
            options: {
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        stacked: true,
                        grid: {
                            display: false
                        }
                    },
                    y: {
                        stacked: true,
                        grid: {
                            display: false
                        }
                    }

                },
                datasets: {
                    bar: {
                        barThickness: 30
                    }
                }

            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,

        };
```

Everything works as expected the only issue is with this line:

```
label: this.Chart[i].name,
```

where I loop through the name of the label, I have duplicates because one label name can have multiple data associated to it for different months, which is correct behavior.

This is how it looks:

[image: chart]

Is there a way on the chart that I could remove the duplicate label just for display purposes so it looks as:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72237654/2358409

Answer (score 0):

You could remove duplicates from your list using this function

```
function remove_duplicates_safe(arr) {
    var seen = {};
    var ret_arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!(arr[i] in seen)) {
            ret_arr.push(arr[i]);
            seen[arr[i]] = true;
        }
    }
    return ret_arr;

}
```

You can then do something like this or make any logic you need

var listNoDuplicates = remove_duplicates_safe(this.Chart);

replace this line

for (var i = 0; i < this.Chart.length; i++) {

with this line

for (var i = 0; i < listNoDuplicates.length; i++) {

Comment: no the array list  has the same label name but different values in it,i can have multiple different values for a single label name,so i cant change the list.

Comment: But you can create a new list wich contains the labels only and use that list in your code? Maby have two for loop or a if stament?